# How to check if a textbox has no value

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an user interface in which I have a textbox (`smartTextBox5`) where I must introduce a value. The application should do something if the value is >1 and something else if it is smaller.

This is my code:

```
double nInterval;

nInterval = double.Parse(smartTextBox5.Value);

if (nInterval > 1)
{
 //do something

}
else 
{
 //do something else
}
```

It works fine if I introduce some values but it crashes if I let the textbox without any value or if I introduce in the textbox only a minus (`-`).

Any ideas?

Comment: If you need to check the string value, then use string.IsNullOrWhitespace(). To avoid exception here, you can use double.TryParse() method.

So, to sum up.. If you need to check if the value is a valid double, then use TryParse method. If you need to check if textbox has any text, use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() on smartTxtBox.Value property.
double.TryParse() will return false even if you got some text which cannot be converted to double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for string being a valid number:

```
double nInterval;
if (Double.TryParse(smartTextBox5.Value, out nInterval)
{
    if (nInterval > 1)
    {
     //do something

    }
    else 
    {
     //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt there is a better way of doing this. I was wrong, I would prefer @Dovydas Sopa's version to reduce nesting.

Comment: those 2 answers do not give the same result, idea is the same, but behavior is different

Answer (score 2):

Your value must be number? You canuse any type (int, double, long. etc.) depending on your needs.

```
int value;
if (int.TryParse(smartTextBox5.Value, out value) && 1 < value) {
     // Valid number.
} else {
     // Invalid number.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Double.TryParse()`, this method will give `True` back if the conversion was successful and `False` if not. In your case it will return `False` if the value of the TextBox is empty or a invalid char like "-".
See the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for further information.

```
if (Double.TryParse(smartTextBox5.Value, out nInterval))
{
   if(nInterval > 1)
      .
      .
      .
}
```